# fetch price from different table woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

i have a plugin called wp deposits and a template called automotive, i need the client to be able to pay a non refundable fee of 5% which is working fine through wp deposits, the thing is wp deposit is picking price from woocommerce, i want it to pick from another table, or i want woocommerce to get products from another table e.g. the prices should come like, select price from another_table where guid=$_GET['guid'];

EDIT: I am new to woocommerce, i have tried researching but havent gotten any resource to help,i went through almost all pages in woocommerce but i cant understand it.

Comment: You can access custom tables via [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), with woocommerce you can overwrite it's templates via a child theme, but not sure can you edit or how it calculates prices. Don't know much about wp deposits.

Comment: hey @D.Dan, thank you for your response, is there a way then that i can insert select from another table into woocommerce products table?

Comment: Of course! If you know exactly where to insert... But this could get very dangerous very quickly if something goes wrong.

Comment: @D.Dan, i'm sorry, i know the tables where the data should come from but i dont know how to insert into woocommerce tables, i have searched but not able to do the above task, i know the logic, so please if you can help me, and if your concern is what i have tired to achieve this, its alot of research but nothing to help. Kindly help me.